$\omega\times\omega$-Hadamard matrices
In the following, we define infinite Hadamard matrices.
Let $\omega$ be the set of non-negative integers. If $f,g:\omega\to\{-1,1\}$ are maps, then we say $f,g$ are approximately orthogonal if  $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \big(f(k)\cdot g(k)\big)=0.$$
An infinite Hadamard matrix is a map $M:\omega^2 \to \{-1,1\}$ such that whenever $i\neq j \in\omega$ then the "row vectors" $M[i,\cdot]$ and $M[j,\cdot]$ are approximately orthogonal. (Given $a\in\omega$, the map $M[a,\cdot]:\omega\to\{-1,1\}$ is defined by $n\mapsto M(a, n)$.)
Question. What is an example of an infinite Hadamard matrix?

Saying that lim.sup equals lim.inf is the same as saying that lim exists with that value.  So your condition just says that $f(k)\cdot g(k)$ is summable with sum $0$.  Which can't happen because $f(k)\cdot g(k)$ does not tend to $0$.  What did you really mean to write?

LaTeX tip: \limsup and \liminf exist.

Right, I have to remove $\lim\sup$. Thanks @Gro-Tsen

One example would be the universal orthogonal array from the theory of factorial experimental design. The matrix is presented below, followed by its mathematical description.
$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
—&{i=0}&1&2&3&4&5&...\\
j=0&1&1&1&1&1&1&...\\
j=1&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1&...\\
j=2&1&1&-1&-1&1&1&...\\
j=3&1&-1&-1&1&1&-1&...\\
j=4&1&1&1&1&-1&-1&...\\
j=5&1&-1&1&-1&-1&1&...\\
...&...&...&...&...&...&...&...\end{array}$
Let the column number $i$ and row number $j$ be defined as indicated above. Express each as its binary representation according to
$i=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_{ik}2^k$
$j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_{jk}2^k$
$b_{ik},b_{jk}\in\{0,1\}$
(Sums are written to infinity, but for any finite coordinates only finitely many terms are nonzero.)
Then the entry in column $i$, riw $j$ is given by
$\exp_{-1}[\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (b_{ik}b_{jk})]$
where $\exp_{-1}$ is use to mean exponential with base $-1$, this nomenclature being used to simplify subscripting. This matrix is exactly orthogonal if it is truncated to $2^n$ rows and $2^n$ columns for any whole number $n$, the resulting truncated arrays then representing the treatments for different factors in a two-level factorial experimental design matrix.

Thanks a lot Oscar! Actually it occurred to me that the most natural definition for approximately orthogonal would be: there is a global constant $C_0\in\omega$ such that $\big|\sum_{k=0}^n \big(f(n)g(n)\big)\big| < C_0$ for all $n\in\omega$. I think your example works with this as well

It would not work for that more restrictive rule, nor could any IMO. You are pigeonholed into having indefinitely long parts of rows or columns all $1$ or all $-1$. But the fraction of such row or column pairs diminishes for larger truncations of this matrix.

For example, if we compute the "inner product" of columns $1,2$ we get the following partial sums: $1,0,-1,0,... $ (and then it repeats). Thus the $\liminf$ would be $-1$.

You nay wnt to pur absolute values aroubd the lim inf argument.

@OscarLanzi I am not sure your argument works - see the comment here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477848/almost-orthogonal-maps-f-omega-to-1-1

@DominicvanderZypen in the comment to the referenced question the dot product of $f_k$ and $f_{2k}$ gets as big absolutely as $k$
for any whole number $k$ by truncating after any odd multiple of $k$
terms. You are still pigeonholed.

OK I see thanks.
